# Error in Formatting through <apex:outputText> tag

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am formatting my field in my Visualforce Email Template. so when i am trying to do this it is giving me this error

**Data type of Monthly CC Vol is currency**

> The value attribute on  is not in a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.

Here is my code

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,###,###.##}">
    Monthly CC Vol $:   <apex:param value="${!relatedTo.Deal_Name__r.Monthly_CC_Vol__c}"/> 
    </apex:outputText><br/>
```

Comment: remove `number` from outputtext.

Comment: No still it is giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` outside from the value attribute.

```
   <apex:outputText value="{0,number,###,###.##}">
        Monthly CC Vol $:   <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Deal_Name__r.Monthly_CC_Vol__c}"/> 
    </apex:outputText><br/>
```